# jupyterでpython3.4を起動したい

Tags: python, anaconda

jupyter notebookでpython3.4環境を起動したいのですが、python3.5になってしまいます。

anacondaを使用しpython環境を構築しています。
python3.4環境、python3.5環境がそれぞれあります。

```
(py34) hama-no-MacBook-Pro:py34 hama$ conda info
Current conda install:

     platform : osx-64
     conda version : 4.1.11
     conda-env version : 2.5.1
     conda-build version : 1.21.0
     python version : 3.5.1.final.0
     requests version : 2.10.0
     root environment : /Users/hama/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2.5.0     (writable)
     default environment : /Users/hama/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2.5.0/envs/py34
     envs directories : /Users/hama/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2.5.0/envs
     package cache : /Users/hama/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2.5.0/pkgs
     channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
                    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
                    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
     config file : None
     offline mode : False
     is foreign system : False
```

anacondaで作成した環境は以下のとおりです。

```
(py34) hama-no-MacBook-Pro:py34 hama$ conda info -e

# conda environments:

#

nn                       /Users/hama/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2.5.0/envs/nn

py27                     /Users/hama/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2.5.0/envs/py27

py34                  *  /Users/hama/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2.5.0/envs/py34

tensorflow               /Users/hama/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2.5.0/envs/tensorflow

root                     /Users/hama/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2.5.0
```

pythonのバージョンは以下です。

```
(py34) hama-no-MacBook-Pro:py34 hama$ python --version
Python 3.4.1 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)
```

この状態でnotebookを立ち上げます。

```
(py34) hama-no-MacBook-Pro:py34 hama$ jupyter notebook
[I 12:37:15.236 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying     another port.
[I 12:37:15.238 NotebookApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 12:37:15.247 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/hama/python/py34
```

jupyter notebook から [new]-[python3]を開いて以下のコードを打ちます。

```
import sys
sys.version
```

以下の通りバージョンが3.4ではなく3.5で起動してしまいます。

```
'3.5.1 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]'
```

どのようにすればpython3.4で起動できますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。
以下を実施しました。

```
(py34) hama-no-MacBook-Pro:py34 hama$ conda install notebook ipykernel

(py34) hama-no-MacBook-Pro:py34 hama$ ipython kernel install --user
```

Installed kernelspec python3 in /Users/hama/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3

Comment: 解決されたみたいで良かったですね！自分自身で問題の解決済マーク(確か、回答の左側にある▲▼の下あたり)をつけると良いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問してから48時間経過しないと解決済みマークが付けれませんので後日付けます。